# In a RabbitMQ topic exchange, should each queue have a unique routing key? Or should each connection have only one queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am using a RabbitMQ topic exchange to route messages in a microservice environment. I understand how Queues work, but I'm uncertain of the intended relationship between a Queue and a subscription to a routing key. For this example, let's assume that each Queue will only ever have one connection (service) bound to it.

1. Should each service only have one queue on which every routing key sub is bound?
2. Should each queue only have one routing key bound to it?